# is there a way to check if alias exists in a cypress test

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, alias

I am trying to solve a problem and haven't found a good solution.

My organization has some tests that create user emails when they run and other times they don't. When the user email is created for tests it isassigned an alias `@userEmail`. I want to write a function in the after hook which will run for ALL tests no matter if the user alias was created/assigned or not.

The function will basically check if the `@userEmail` alias exists. If it does run a DB query to clear our the user else do nothing.

this is how the alias is being created in our `/cypress/support/actions/user-setup.js` file

```js
const setupEmail = function (alias) {
  cy.wrap(getEmail(alias)).as('userEmail');
};
```

and this is my `aftereach()` method

```js
afterEach(function () {
  
  cy.get('@userEmail').then((email) => {
    cy.dbQuery('clearSSNandPhoneNumber', email);
  });
});
```

Now this works perfectly for tests where an alias is created. However, if a test doesn't create the alias, the afterEach function fails the whole test.

Seems like this isn't a suggested way of checking for aliases. How do I create a work around where the DB query will be run if an alias exists and do nothing if it doesn't exist?

Comment: There may be a better approach to what you are wanting to do with cypress. At our company we have a separate cron job that will clear all our automation created data.  That may be better than trying to clear the user emails after each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) will check the alias without failing the test if it doesn't exist.

```js
afterEach(() => {
  cy.get('@userEmail')
    .if()
    .log('Cleaning db')
    .dbQuery('clearSSNandPhoneNumber', email)
    .else()
    .log('No cleanup required')
})
```

The aliases are actually available in `cy.state()` if you prefer.

```js
afterEach(() => {

  // with no aliases set up
  console.log(cy.state('aliases'))                               // undefined

  cy.wrap('email').as('userEmail').then(() => {
    expect(cy.state('aliases').userEmail).to.not.be.undefined    // passes
  })

  if (cy.state('aliases')?.userEmail) {                    // NB ?.userEmail
    cy.dbQuery('clearSSNandPhoneNumber', email)
  }
})
```

Comment: Cy.state() worked. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see cy.state() in version 9

Comment: Yes it's an internal function. Like conditional testing, it's not officially sanctioned by Cypress but often used as a pragmatic backdoor.

Answer (score 0):

My use is geared towards an alias created by a cy.intercept() call, but seems to work well. Of course I would be happy to hear any feedback why it's not a preferred approach!

```
verify_api_NOT_called(alias: string) {
    cy.get(alias).then(value => {
      expect(value).to.be.null;
    });
  }
```